# How can I fix error during install a package with APT in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, apt, dpkg

I was trying to install a package using APT and I got error:

```
UserName@PCname:~$ sudo apt-get install php7.2

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
php7.2 is already the newest version (7.2.7-1+0~20180622080852.23+jessie~1.gbpfd8e2e).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up php7.1-fpm (7.1.18-1+0~20180611145758.18+jessie~1.gbp2b32f6) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/php7.1-fpm.postinst: 2: /etc/apache2/envvars: =/var/run/apache2: not found
dpkg: error processing package php7.1-fpm (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Setting up libapache2-mod-php7.2 (7.2.7-1+0~20180622080852.23+jessie~1.gbpfd8e2e) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libapache2-mod-php7.2.postinst: 2: /etc/apache2/envvars: =/var/run/apache2: not found
dpkg: error processing package libapache2-mod-php7.2 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Setting up libapache2-mod-php7.1 (7.1.18-1+0~20180611145758.18+jessie~1.gbp2b32f6) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libapache2-mod-php7.1.postinst: 2: /etc/apache2/envvars: =/var/run/apache2: not found
dpkg: error processing package libapache2-mod-php7.1 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of php7.2:
 php7.2 depends on libapache2-mod-php7.2 | php7.2-fpm | php7.2-cgi; however:
  Package libapache2-mod-php7.2 is not configured yet.
  Package php7.2-fpm is not installed.
  Package php7.2-cgi is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package php7.2 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 php7.1-fpm
 libapache2-mod-php7.2
 libapache2-mod-php7.1
 php7.2
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you try `sudo apt install --fix-broken` and/or `sudo apt install php7.2-fpm php7.2-cgi`

Comment: @Fanatique - The option `-f`/`--fix-broken` belongs to `apt-get`, not `apt` (at least on Ubuntu 16.04.4). I would suggest running `sudo apt-get` in three successive runs with the parameters `update`, `check` and `-f --reinstall install php7.2`.

Comment: It doesn't works :((

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This commands helps me:

1) Remove PHP and all his libraries and files

```
sudo apt-get purge php7.*
```

2) Install PHP again

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2
```

Comment: This removes all php libraries version 7.something with their configuration. I'm not sure this is the right solution for everyone here.

Comment: @JoeEifert Maybe it will be useful for someone

Answer (score 1):

It seems there's a bug in the php7.1 for the Ubuntu distribution: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php7.1/+bug/1710007

The issue can be fixed running the following commands before installing "libapache2-mod-php7.1":

```bsh
sudo apt-get remove --purge php* -y && apt-get purge libapache2-mod-php* -y
```